# Phalcon create Link with get parameters

Tags: hyperlink, query-string, phalcon, volt

Is there a helper function in phalcon (volt) to create Links to routes with GET-Parameters ? I have pagination-links on which I want to add ?cat=category and ?year=year depending on whether they are set or not.

```
<a href="{{ url.getBaseUri() }}tags/{{ tagname.tag }}">First</a>
<a href="{{ url.getBaseUri() }}tags/{{ tagname.tag }}?page=<?= $page->before; ?>">Previous</a>
<a href="{{ url.getBaseUri() }}tags/{{ tagname.tag }}?page=<?= $page->next; ?>">Next</a>
<a href="{{ url.getBaseUri() }}tags/{{ tagname.tag }}?page=<?= $page->last; ?>">Last</a>
```

so that

```
http://site.tld/tags/xyz?page=2
```

would become:

```
http://site.tld/tags/xyz?cat=a&year=b&page=2
```

or this, if cat is not set or null:

```
http://site.tld/tags/xyz?year=b&page=2
```

**edit**

this way it seems to work:

```
<a href="{{ pagingurl ~ page.first }}">First</a>
<a href="{{ pagingurl ~ page.before }}">Previous</a>
<a href="{{ pagingurl ~ page.next }}">Next</a>
<a href="{{ pagingurl ~ page.last }}">Last</a>
```

the rest happens in the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it's easier to do that in the controller than using volt.
First, generate the base URL for your pagination links with the [URL Service](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/url.html):

```
$pagingUrl = $this->url->get('tags/' . $tagname->tag);
```

Now you can get 'cat' and 'year' with something like `$this->request->getPost('cat');` to check if it's set and append it to `$pagingUrl` as GET parameters. Leave a '&page=' at end of the `$pagingUrl` to easily append the page number later.

Set `$page` and `$pagingUrl` as variables for your view so you can easily access it from volt:

```
$this->view->setVar('page', $page);
$this->view->setVar('pagingUrl', $pagingUrl);
```

Finally in the view you could use something like that:

```
{{ link_to(pagingUrl ~ '1', 'First') }}
{{ link_to(pagingUrl ~ page.before, 'Previous') }}
{{ link_to(pagingUrl ~ page.next, 'Next') }}
{{ link_to(pagingUrl ~ page.last, 'Last') }}
```

---

#### EDIT

The solutions above seems hackish because Phalcon designers aimed to work more with [clean URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL) than explicit GET parameters. If you were passing your parameters this way, your `TagController` could have an action that supports pagination like this:

```
class TagController
{
  ...
  public function ListAction($page = 1, $category = 'default-cat', $year = 1997)
  {
    ...
```

Working that way you can easily create links like these:

- `tags/list`
- `tags/list/2/stuff`
- `tags/list/9/stuff/2014`

Comment: ok. i will try it, but think it could be problematic to deal with ? or & in front of page.x thats why i thought of something like [http_build_query](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) in the view

Comment: ok that looks clean. i'm using explicit GET parameters there, because the user can choose the order of filtering. e.g. /cat/year or /year/cat .that means I would have to find out which is first with a DB request. I have it like in the hackish solution. will add an edit to my question